# whenever gem is throwing "can't iterate from Time" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever, ruby-2.0

I'm using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)  for crone job but when I run it :

```
cd ~/my_project
whenever
```

I get error

```
/home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1@my_projcet/bundler/gems/rails-d1904aff6f04/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/include_range.rb:16:in `each': can't iterate from Time (TypeError)
```

I'm running

ruby-2.0.0-rc1 and 
rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error was caused by **chronic** gem (a **whenever gem** dependency): it was colliding with **Ruby 2**. You can solve it with a simple `bundle update whenever chronic` and you'll get the latest, non-colliding version.

In the future, if you need a fix before a new version of Chronic is officially released, point your `Gemfile` directly at the git repo:

```
gem 'chronic', :git => 'git@github.com:mojombo/chronic.git'
gem 'whenever'
```

Comment: `bundle update whenever chronic` will handle it now, since chronic released a fixed gem

Comment: What was happening in the code that caused the collision with Ruby 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `whenever` to handle Ruby 2.

```
bundle update whenever
```